# How can I analyse System Calls in Windows using Java?

Tags: java, windows, system, system-calls

I need to profile user behaviour by using system calls. Which log file of system or which Java API can I use to analyse system calls?

Comment: There is no logs for system calls on windows. But there is some API on c. Google for WinAPI and trace

Answer (score 1):

What you need is the Windows Event Viewer. You can read this https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/kb/308427.

However there is no direct way to read them from Java. I think there is a way to export these Logs to CSV and then Java can read them.

You need to use C++ and a Windows API to really get the list of System calls or pull some kernel events out.